# How do I redirect to another website without the referrer displaying my website?

Tags: redirect, referrer

I would rather it just display nothing, or another website.  I don't want it to display any website that I am affiliated with.

Comment: We need a lot more information, what are you using on your website? PHP? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL shortener, such as bit.ly to make the link.  That way you're once removed, there may still be trace but it won't be as obvious in the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Use short url in your web link. such as [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/)

user see the tiny url instead of the real url. They couldn't see the website that you are affiliated with

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect from an HTTPS page to a URL with a different domain then no referrer will be sent by the browser to avoid leaking information. This will save you from relying on any third parties.